# Disable hover on specific points/bar - Plotly

Tags: python, plot, plotly

I'm working on displaying a bar chart, where for some of the bars there is relevant information to be shown to the user, but on some of the bar there is no information.

Is it possible to disable the hover information on the bars with no relevant information?.

[image]
In my example, I would like to hide information on all the white bars.

This is as minimum working example.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

d = {'Lobnr.': [1, 2, 3, 4,5], 'Plads':[21,22,23,24,25], 'Val':[1,1,1,1,1], 'Status kode': [np.nan, 1,1,2,np.nan], 
    'Ordrenr': [np.nan, 231,213,222,np.nan], 'pll pladser': [np.nan,12,3,15,np.nan], 'pll': [np.nan,19,20,30,np.nan], 'color': ['white', 'yellow', 
                                                                                            'yellow', 'green', 'white'],}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

fig = px.bar(df,x='Plads', y='Val', color=df['color'], color_discrete_map='identity', hover_data={'Val':False,
                                                'Ordrenr':True,
                                                'pll pladser':True, 
                                                'pll':True,
                                                'Plads':False},
            text='Plads')
fig.show()
```

Comment: @ChristianAndersn Your code snippet will not reproduce your plot. Please share full code to reproduce your plot along with a sample of your data.

Comment: @vestland Sorry about that, I have update the example, so it is possible to reproduce